# Best way to send source maps to Sentry but keep them off production website and app

Tags: vue.js, webpack, github-actions, sentry, source-maps

I have a Ionic Vue web-based PWA and web-based mobile app. Recently I added Sentry into the mix and used the Sentry webpack plugin to upload source maps to Sentry. Everything works great when the Vue/JavaScript crashes I get the proper line/column info on the error but I noticed on the web-based version of the app that webpack shows the source code for the entire Vue app. I'd like to prevent that.

Here is my workflow: I commit to github `main` and it kicks off a github action which builds the project and finally deploys to Firebase hosting. I'm thinking I need to have two actions, one for building and sending to Firebase, and another for building and uploading source maps. I also use Ionic AppFlow for deploying to mobile apps (iOS/Android) so I'm thinking I need to prevent AppFlow from building/sending sourcemaps too.

So... how do I do this? Both Github actions and AppFlow see things as "production" mode. And AppFlow doesn't support environment variables at the pay level I'm at. Is there a way to have multiple `vue.config.js` files I can have?

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple `vue.config.js` files - but each one of them must live in its own Git branch. Then, when you commit to the `main_pwa` branch - it will use the `vue.config.js` for the PWA and when you commit to `main_mobile` branch it will use the `vue.config.js` for the Ionic app. If this option does not suit you - your Github action(s) should provide the correct `vue.config.js` file for the corresponding build, probably by overwriting the file inplace.